# Brown-ish spots on Bonsai (Carmona) leaves

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, leaves, bonsai

Today while trimming my bonsai, I've noticed some brown spots on some leaves. Most, if not all yellowed leaves had these spots on them. These spots seem to be "raised" (not flush with the leaves surface - and by the looks of it, the yellower the leaf, the more bumpy the spots).

There were a bunch of leaves that were still green, but they had these spots. To be on the safe side, I've tried to cut all the spotty leaves. The tree is healthy, with a bunch of leaves, and there were not that many "marked" leaves to cause any harm to it.

I'd like to mention that the plant is an indoor plant, and it's location has been the same for the past year or so. Temps have been "constant" (no major fluctuations), same with humidity. Watering and other aspects haven't changed either (soaking every few days).

I'll attach a couple of images with some leaves where the browning can be seen, with varying levels of yellowing:

[image: Overall look]

[image: Zoomed in]

Has anyone else experienced this before? Any ideas what this might be, and in case it's harmful, how to treat it?

Comment: Whenever you have any such issues you round up the usual suspects. If it's an indoor plant, some of them don't apply but others do. Any insects or fungus? (Use a magnifying glass.) Any changes such as water, fertilizer, air flow, light? Indoor, is it near a heating or A/C vent? Outdoor check for nearby chemicals such as herbicide, road salt, paint, etc.

Comment: Completely forgot to add those details! I've just edited my post, and added these aspects too.
tl;dr: no major environmental changes - same temps, location, watering, etc.

Haven't seen any bugs, but will keep an eye out now that I noticed the spots. Don't know about it being fungal...
Posted here to see if anyone has had anything remotely similar, and what was their experience.